# average length of stay in hospital calculation

Tags: mean, descriptive-statistics

I need to calculate the average LOS (Length Of Stay) over 15 years. My formula is the following:

`total number of days in hospital (for each patient) / total number of patients discharged`

Because I need to express this average per patient/year I was thinking to do the following:

`{total number of days in hospital (for each patient)/total number of patients discharged}/15`

Is this correct?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: What is the purpose of this calculation? Is it to report a fact about the data or is it to estimate a parameter in a model of length of stay?  (The three answers so far all implicitly assume the latter.) Note, too, that there is subtlety here that becomes apparent when shorter periods are considered: your calculation should (somehow) account for patients who are currently in the hospital.

Answer (score 2):

(1) How are you managing deaths and hospital transfers? are they excluded from the numerator as well. Any methods is reasonable, just need to document.
(2) The mean is almost never used in LOS. Usually median with IQR. You do have a big outlier problem. 
(3) I must be missing something. But what is `{total number of days in hospital (for each patient)/total number of patients discharged}/15` ? This number has no meaning and unclear from your post what you want to achieve. Though since others don't seemed bothered, I'd just ignore me on this.

Comment: Charles is on to something.  Unless there are patients staying more than one year, it doesn't matter whether the time period under consideration is 15 years or 1 year:  the mean LOS is still Days/Admissions.  Dividing by 15 will give 1/15 of the mean LOS.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, yes it is correct. However I think you should look at the distribution of the number of days in hospital.

If there are lot of people who spend very few days in hospital and few people who spend a lot of days in the hospital, the average calculated may be misleading because you will get an artificially high number.

If you graph the distribution and see that there are a few outliers, you might want to consider the trimmed mean (i.e. just exclude the outliers). Another option is the weighted average.